# Why are my speech recognition results getting overridden?

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition

I have a webpage that records user's speech and appends it to an HTML form. The code is "working", but once the speech recognition stops and then restarts, the new speech-to-text data overrides the first box's data. I want to have the next restarted speech to text only appended to the second box, not the first, while keeping the first box's data there.

JS:

```
<form class="texts" action="/care" id="careid" name="care" method="POST">
                      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="what's your name?">
                      <input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Where are you?">
                      <input type="text" id="state" placeholder="how can I help?">
                      <input id="buttonInput" class="btn btn-success form-control" type="submit" value="Send">
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script>
              window.SpeechRecognition =
                window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

              const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
              recognition.interimResults = true;

              let p = document.createElement('p');


              recognition.addEventListener("result", (e) => {
                const text = Array.from(e.results)
                document.getElementById("name").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                }
              );

              recognition.addEventListener("end", () => {
                recognition.start();
                recognition.addEventListener("result", (e) => {
                  const text = Array.from(e.results)
                  document.getElementById("location").value = event.results[0][0].transcript;
                });
              });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about defining a default value variable for the input tags, instead of add value straight to the form, you can assign it to the variable then get its updates in the form.

Comment: I like that idea, but how would I do that? I'm a little confused

Answer (score 0):

We can put the inputs in an array and have a counter tell us which one to write to.

```
let counter = 0;
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')
recognition.addEventListener("result", (e) => {
  if (inputs.length< counter) inputs[counter].value = e.results[0][0].transcript;
  counter++;
});
```

Comment: Close. I have an input id for name and one for location. I want the first speech recognition event to have it's transcript appended to name, then I want it to restart and have the next recognition event append its transcript to location.